# Issues getting PHP to display in category pages

Tags: php, templates

I am using this code to display social media share links at the top of my posts. Currently, they display fine on my pages and posts. Is there any way to get this to display also on my category pages? Another option that would work is getting the code to display everywhere below the H1 and content, I don't think there are any pages where I don't want these buttons so perhaps this is the easier solution.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated ☺️

```
function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    global $post;
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = urlencode(get_permalink());

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = htmlspecialchars(urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        // $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
        $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;
        $linkedInURL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;title='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $variable .= '<!-- Implement your own social sharing buttons without any JavaScript loading. No plugin required. Detailed steps here: http://crunchify.me/1VIxAsz -->';
        $variable .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank">Buffer</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-linkedin" href="'.$linkedInURL.'" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>';
        $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
        $variable .= '</div>';

        return $variable.$content;
    }else{
        // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $variable.$content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
```

Here is my category.php, as requested

```
<?php
/**
 * The Category template file.
 *
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Zeal
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <div class="container archive-page">

                <div class="row">

                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                            <header class="page-header">
                                <h1 class="page-title"><h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
                            </header><!-- .page-header -->                                          
<?php 
the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' ); 
?>
<hr class="wp-block-separator">
<div id="category-menu"><a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/">All</a>&nbsp;<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/education/">Education</a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/industrial/">Industrial</a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/leisure/">Leisure</a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/medical/">Medical</a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/military/">Military</a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/other/">Other</a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/religious/">Religious</a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/residential/">Residential</a>&nbsp;
</br>
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/austria/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/belgium/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/bulgaria/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/france/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/germany/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/great-britain/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/hungary/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/italy/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/japan/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/luxembourg/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/portugal/"> </a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/romania/"></a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/ukraine/"> </a>&nbsp;
<a class="category-link" href="https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/usa/"></a>&nbsp;</div>
</br>
                            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                    <?php
                                    /**
                                     * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                                     */
                                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'category' );
                                    ?>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

                    <?php else : ?>

                            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </main><!-- #main -->

    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You can simply add `is_post_archive()` to the if condition. See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/ for all the available tests.

Comment: I have just tried this, and it still does not show on the category pages

Comment: Changed first lines of code to this, but still no effect:

function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    global $post;
    if(is_singular() || is_home() || is_post_archive()){

Comment: I tried other conditional tags, and it still doesn't display. Is there any other way? :(

Comment: @Obsidian what does your category template's code look like? At the moment you're hooking you function to `the_content`. Is it used somewhere on the category template?

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen I have added my category.php code to my initial comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your category.php I assume you're using the Zeal theme, which means that `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'category' )` probably spits out something like this, https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/zeal/1.0.8/template-parts/content-category.php, but do correct me, if I'm wrong.

Based on this assumption I'd say there is no `the_content` hook available in your loop, so your `crunchify_social_sharing_buttons` function never gets executed. But you should be able to use `the_excerpt` filter, as `the_excerpt` is used in the template part file, to achieve the same result. To do that you need to slightly modify your code - just move the social media link generation to a separate function, which you then hook to both `the_content` and `the_excerpt`.

Like so,

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
function the_content_crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
  return (is_singular() || is_home()) ? crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) : $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'the_excerpt_crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
function the_excerpt_crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($excerpt) {
  return (is_archive()) ? crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($excerpt) : $excerpt;
}

function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
  global $post;

  // Get current page URL 
  $crunchifyURL = urlencode(get_permalink());

  // Get current page title
  $crunchifyTitle = htmlspecialchars(urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
  // $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

  // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
  $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

  // Construct sharing URL without using any script
  $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
  $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
  $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
  $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;
  $linkedInURL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;title='.$crunchifyTitle;

  // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
  $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

  // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
  $variable = '<div class="crunchify-social">';
  $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
  $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
  $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
  $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank">Buffer</a>';
  $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-linkedin" href="'.$linkedInURL.'" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>';
  $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
  $variable .= '</div>';

  return $variable.$content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I tried your updated code but I still dont see the share buttons in my category pages. Do I need to alter the category.php or content-category.php as well?

Comment: @Obsidian You should check the `content-category.php` template to see, if it actually includes `the_excerpt()` template tag. Another thing you can do is to inspect the page source too see, if the sharing div is added, but not visible due to some css issue.

Comment: Ok, I put an the_excerpt() tag into category.php and then this worked so I dont think content_category.php is needed for this.

Can I hook this to the_archive_description() instead of the_excerpt()? I tried and it didn't work. My category pages display this anyway so this would be a perfect solution.

Comment: @Obsidian Yes, putting the hook on the main file is also ok. The main point is just to have the hook present so that you can attach custom functions to it. Yes you can also hook the function to the archive description tag. In that case the filter is `get_the_archive_description`, which accepts one string parameter so you can just swap the filter name and it should work then.

Comment: Thank you,  I changed the_excerpt filter to the following at it works perfectly


add_filter( 'get_the_archive_description', 'get_the_archive_description_crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
function get_the_archive_description_crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($description) {
  return (is_archive()) ? crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($description) : $description;
}

Comment: @Obsidian Good to hear. You can mark my answer as the accepted one to let the WPSE community know, you're question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to add is_post_archive, but also your filter 'the_content' is for posts. You can call your function directly from category.php or change the hook.

[the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)